# Spring data mongodb does not work with spring data jpa in spring webmvc applicaition

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-web

I have a legacy spring mvc web application which uses spring data jpa 1.9.5. Same application breaks as soon as I add dependency for spring data mongodb 1.9.5.

POM:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Error shows

> Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/projection/ProjectionFactory;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
>       at   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435)
>       at
>    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220)

Which version of spring data jpa is compatible with spring data mongodb. ?

Comment: Hello, I'm a little confused. Why do you need both `spring-data-jpa`and `spring-data-mongodb` ?

Comment: because i have use case of storing data in both oracle and mongo db.

Comment: Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Mongo have different versioning schemes. So version 1.9.5 from one is totally different from 1.9.5 from the other. Instead of manually cobling together the correct version use the Spring Data release train bom, that way you know you have the correct versions.